# File Upload to Ftp Server From Local System

Tags: c#

The Below is my program in c# to connect to Ftp Server.While Uploading the .txt file from local system to ftp server i am getting the error "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found". Please help me on this so that I can resolve my error.

The below is the free ftp server what i am using to up-load the file with username and password

Location: http://demo.wftpserver.com/
Username: demo-user
Password: demo-user

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ftp testConnec = new Ftp();
            testConnec.CheckFTPConnection("http://demo.wftpserver.com/");
            testConnec.uploadFileToFTP(@"C:\TestFtpConnection", "test_new.txt", "upload", "http://demo.wftpserver.com");    
        }
        public class Ftp
        {
            #region checkFTPConnection

            public bool CheckFTPConnection(string URL)
            {
                // Uri myUri = new Uri("http://demo.wftpserver.com/");
                Uri myUri = new Uri(URL);
                //  WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);

                //FtpWebRequest myRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
                WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
                myRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("demo-admin", "demo-admin");
                myRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;

                try
                {
                    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

                    long i = myResponse.ContentLength;
                    return true;
                    myResponse.Close();

                }
                // catch (Exception ex)
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
            #endregion

            public bool uploadFileToFTP(string LocalFilePath, string FileName, string Directory,string URL)
            {

                try
                {
                    Uri myUri = new Uri(URL);
                    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
                    WebRequest ftpClient = WebRequest.Create(myUri + Directory + "/" + FileName);
                    ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("demo-admin", "demo-admin");
                    ftpClient.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                    System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(LocalFilePath + "/" + FileName);
                    ftpClient.ContentLength = fi.Length;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
                    int bytes = 0;
                    int total_bytes = (int)fi.Length;
                    System.IO.FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
                    System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
                    while (total_bytes > 0)
                    {
                        bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
                    }
                    //fs.Flush();
                    fs.Close();
                    rs.Close();
                    WebResponse uploadResponse = ftpClient.GetResponse();
                    // string value = uploadResponse.StatusDescription;
                    uploadResponse.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: have you tried using `ftp` instead of `http` protocol? Like this: `testConnec.CheckFTPConnection("http://demo.wftpserver.com/");`